# How to load multiple har files on one pig load command?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata, har

I have many har files based which is archived by hours, and I would like to analysis the data based on month and day. I tried different wildcard matching methods which supported by pig load and works well for non archived folders and files but none of them work for har.

This is how i tried:

```
LOAD 'har:///2015092???.har/2015092???/aaa/*/ttt.txt.gz'
LOAD 'har:///2015092{12,13}.har/2015092???/aaa/*/ttt.txt.gz' AS
```

Is there any way I can load multiple har files on one pig command instead of load them one by one?